# Date format changing to 2000-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-00:00"

Tags: android, date, datetime, date-formatting, iso8601

What is format of this string date ""2000-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-00:00" ?
I watch:

```
 yy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz
```

but what is ".0000000-00:00"?

Thanx

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I was there beffore, but i not find solution..But tnx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read This : [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Here,

```
You defined : yy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz   
You Got : 2000-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-00:00
```

Means :

```
yyyy - year (2000)
MM - Month (01)
dd - Date (01)

HH - hour in day (0-23)
mm - minute in hour (30)
ss : second in minute (59)
```

Now Your Solution...

```
SSS : fractional seconds
z : time zone (Pacific Standard Time)
```

Means You Got [TimeZone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) which is -00:00

Answer (score 3):

```
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1969-12-31
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1970-01-01
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1969-12-31 16:00
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1970-01-01 00:00
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1969-12-31 16:00-0800
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1970-01-01 00:00+0000
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31 16:00:00.000-0800
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000+0000
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-0800
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000
```